# Репост сообщений ботом. Как сделать?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram

У меня есть простой телеграм-бот на python для отправки периодических уведомлений в чат-группу. Всё работает, но мне хотелось бы узнать, как сделать так что бы он отправлял репосты бота @postbot? Или репосты обычного пользователя.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import telegram
import time

def main():
    bot = telegram.Bot(token='token')
    chat_id=-1041346235343
    message='hello world' 
    interval=54
    while True:
        bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text=message, parse_mode=telegram.ParseMode.HTML)
        time.sleep(interval)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```